# Random crash issue or heap size issue in an Android app

Tags: android, crash, out-of-memory, large-data

I am facing random crash on my application developed for `"GlassDesign"`; the purpose is to showcase their glasses to their clients and to the agents as well.

The app size is 150MB size.

When I am walking through the application that takes 10 to 15 minutes to crash, this is not happening on any particular screen to understand the issue.

I have reed few post and made few changes to application as well.

1. In manifest I done these changes

   ```
   android:largeHeap="true" // in application tag
   android:allowBackup="false" // for cache
   ```
2. On every activity I cleared the existing cache (this also helped to increase the crash to two to three screens but not entire app)

   ```
   public boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
   if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if(!dir.getAbsolutePath().contains("/databases")){
           boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
           if (!success) {
              return false;
           }
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
   }
      return dir.delete();
   }
   ```
3. For loading images I have used universal image loader (external jar file) for better performance.

Comment: what is the size(dimension) of the Images , Which is used in the App....

Comment: thumb images size is 220x160 (used in listing) details gallery images are 1280x800 (400 kb each file)

Comment: the exact image size , Are you  using  in the application . ?

Comment: Yes @AM, but the images count are more (150 projects and 400 images)